# Is DLL loaded in kernel mode or user mode?

Tags: windows, dll, operating-system

I was asked such a question in an interview:

> In windows, suppose there is an exe which depends on some dlls, when you start
>   the exe, and then the dependent dlls will be loaded, are these dlls
>   loaded in kernel mode or user mode?

I am not quite sure about the question, not the mention the answer - could you help to explain?

Thanks.

Comment: In such a case, I would be sooooo very tempted to challenge the assumption that "click the exe" executes it.

Comment: @BenVoigt sorry, I am not quite catch you, but what is the problem with "click the exe" exactly?

Comment: If I click an exe file in Windows Explorer, it becomes selected.  If I click an exe file in Visual Studio, the Resource Editor opens and shows me icon, string, menu, and dialog resources.  If I click an exe file in Dependency Walker, the dependent DLLs are analyzed.  In only one of these cases are the dependent DLLs read from disk, and only as data files, they are not "loaded" (in the sense of the OS library loader).

Comment: @BenVoigt Make sense:) it is my fault that I should simply reword it as "start the exe"

Comment: Linux has dynamically loadable kernel modules with extension .ko (not necessary), they are different from dynamically loadable user libraries which have extension (.so). I do not know if there is a similar distinction in Windows or not. But the answer will come from the analogy.

Comment: Obviously user mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The question is very imprecise/ambiguous.** "In Windows" suggests something but isn't clear what. Likely the interviewer was referring to the Win32 subsystem - i.e. the part of Windows that you usually get to see as an end-user. The last part of the question is even more ambiguous.

Now while process and section objects (in MSDN referred to as MMF, loaded PE images such as `.exe` and `.dll` and `.sys`) *are* indeed **kernel objects** and require some assistance from the underlying executive (and memory manager etc) the respective code in the DLL (including that in `DllMain`) will behave exactly the same as for any other user mode process, *when called from a user mode process*. That is, each thread that is running code from the DLL will transition to kernel mode to make use of OS services eventually (opening files, loading PE files, creating events etc) or do some stuff in user mode whenever that is sufficient.

Perhaps the interviewer was even interested in the memory ranges that are sometimes referred to as "kernel space" and "user space", traditionally at the 2 GB boundary for 32bit. And yes, DLLs usually end up below the 2 GB boundary, i.e. in "user space", while other shared memory (memory mapped files, MMF) usually end up above that boundary.

It is even possible that the interviewer fell victim to a common misunderstanding about DLLs. The DLL itself is merely a dormant piece of memory, it isn't running anything on its own *ever* (and yes, this is also true for `DllMain`). Sure, the loader will take care of all kinds of things such as relocations, but in the end nothing will run without being called explicitly or implicitly (in the context of some thread of the process loading the DLL). So for all practical purposes the question would require you to ask back.

- Define "in Windows".
- Also "dlls loaded in kernel mode or user mode", does this refer to the code doing the loading or to the end result (i.e. where the code runs or in what memory range it gets loaded)? Parts of that code run in user mode, others in kernel mode.

I wonder whether the interviewer has a clear idea of the concepts s/he is asking about.

---

Let me add some more information. It seems from the comments on the other answer that people have the same misconception that exists about DLLs also about drivers. Drivers are much closer to the idea of DLLs than to that of EXEs (or ultimately "processes"). The thing is that a driver doesn't do anything on its own *most of the time* (though it can create system threads to change that). *Drivers are not processes and they do not create processes.*

Comment: No, the comments on the other question are referring to the User-Mode Driver Framework, which changes all the rules you thought applied to drivers.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm confused, they are still not separate processes though. What am I missing? Are there multiple UMDF models? I thought they were basically DLLs just like the kernel mode drivers are also roughly DLLs.

Comment: The UMDF "driver" is a loadable library, but it loads into its own host process.  It doesn't run in-process in the calling application.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. As I said, I'm more of a KM guy anyway when it comes to Windows drivers.

Comment: I totally agree this question is ambiguous, but I am afraid the interviewer is just holding a paper and ask questions accordingly - he is not able to explain what he exactly want to ask... not just for this question:(

Comment: @lzprgmr: assuming this is a job interview, some inquisitive questions about an ambiguous question might get you further than a fuzzy answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert about how Windows internally works, but for what i know the correct answer is user mode, simply because only the processes related to your Operative System are admitted in the kernel space http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/User_Mode_vs_Kernel_Mode

Basically if it's not an OS process, it's going to be allocated in the user space.

Comment: This is correct, but really doesn't go far enough.  Many OS services also run in user mode.  It used to be that you could say that drivers were the loadable components in kernel mode, but these days even some drivers run in user mode.  (Maybe we should call those "device support services", instead of drivers, to maintain the distinction.)

Comment: @BenVoigt about the drivers we could also make a neat and clean distinction about what drivers are digitally signed and "secure" from Microsoft viewpoint and what drivers are not. The concepts of user-space and kernel-space do not care about this implementation details that are instead fundamental for an OS; it depends on what is the question and what is point with this interview.

Comment: Driver signatures don't affect how the driver is loaded.  Without a signature, you're just forced to confirm installation before the driver goes into kernel space.

Comment: @BenVoigt depends, with "a confirmation" i think you mean the UAC, which basically is available only on Vista and 7; Windows is a big project and also pretty old too, too many variables to discuss this in an exhaustive way, i also noticed that many drivers that are not signed have a dedicated process in my user space and not in the kernel space; probably the driver's sign is a term of distinction for Windows in general.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks guys, now I guess the intent of the interviewer is to test if you know that windows API is called in kernel model - when exe loads its dependent dll, it is actually calling LoadLibrary, which will then switch to kernel model to call the native API of LoadLibrary to load the DLL, so the answer may probably be "kernel mode"

Comment: @user: No, the prompt when installing unsigned drivers is totally different from UAC, and already existed in Windows XP.

Comment: @lzprgmr: The DLLs are not loaded into kernel mode.  Kernel mode components may help with the loading process, but that's not what the question appears to be asked for.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: the signatures are checked during the loading phase, there is no confirmation. You'd have to use `bcdedit` to disable that and even then you'll have to test-sign the drivers. Also drivers do not (normally, though just like the kernel they could) create processes and they aren't processes.

Comment: @lzprgmr: it's not calling `LoadLibrary`. How could it, before `kernel32.dll` got loaded? You should read up on the loader, which is implemented largely in NTDLL itself (only occasionally transitioning into kernel mode whenever it needs the kernel to do something).

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Drivers developed with UMDF become user-mode processes.  And the confirmation I'm referring to is during installation, not at load time.

Comment: @BenVoigt: oh, of course. I forgot about those. Too much of a kernel mode guy, I suppose ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite obviously User mode for anybody who does any kind of significant application development for windows. Let me explain two things.

**DLL**

A dynamic link library is closely similar to a regular old link library or .lib. When your application uses a .lib it pastes in function definitions just after compile time. You typically use a .lib to store API's and to modify the functions with out having to rebuild the whole project, just paste new .lib with same name over the old and as long as the interface(function name and parameters) hasn't changed it still works. Great modularity.

A .dll does exactly the same thing however it doesn't require re-linking or any compilation. You can think of a .dll as essentially a .lib which gets compiled to an .exe just the same as applications which use it. Simply put the new .dll which shares the name and function signatures and it all just works. You can update your application simply by replacing .dlls. This is why most windows software consists of .dlls and a few exe's.

The usage of a .dll is done in two ways

**Implicit linking**

To link this way if you had a .dll `userapplication.dll` you would have an `userapplication.lib` which defines all the entry points in the dll. You simply link to the static link library and then include the .dll in the working  directory.

**Explicit linking**

Alernatively you can programmatically load the .dll by first calling `LoadLibrary(userapplication.dll)` which returns a handle to your .dll. Then `GetProcAddress(handle, "FunctionInUserApplicationDll")` which returns a function pointer you can use. This way your application can check stuff before attempting to use it. `c#` is a little different but easier.

**USER/KERNEL MODES**

Windows has two major modes of execution. User mode and Kernel modes (kernel further divided into system and sessions). For user mode the physical memory address is opaque. User mode makes use of virtual memory which is mapped to real memory spaces. User mode driver's are coincidentally also .dll's. A user mode application typically gets around 4Gb of virtual addressing space to work with. Two different applications can not meaningfully use those address because they are with in context of that application or process. There is no way for a user mode application to know it's physical memory address with out falling back to kernel mode driver. Basically everything your used to programming (unless you develop drivers).

Kernel mode is protected from user mode applications. Most hardware drivers work in the context of kernel mode and typically all windows api's are broken into two categories user and kernel. Kernel mode drivers use kernel mode api's and do not use user mode api's and hence don't user .dll's(You can't even print to a console cause that is a user mode api set). Instead they use .sys files which are drivers and essentially work exactly the same way in user mode. A .sys is an pe format so basically an .exe just like a .dll is like an .exe with out a main() entry point.

So from the askers perspective you have two groups

**[kernel/.sys] and [user/.dll or .exe]**

There really isn't .exe's in kernel because the operating system does everything not users. When system or another kernel component starts something they do it by calling DriverEntry() method so I guess that is like main().

So this question in this sense is quite simple.